# Game forces 4k monitor resolution on 1080p monitor

Tags: windows, graphics-card, hdmi, resolution

Laptop: Acer a515-51g

Graphics card: Nvidia Mx150 (471.96 driver version)

Integrated graphics: Intel (R) UHD Graphics 620 (30.0.100.9687)

I bought an external monitor few months back (Acer vg240ys - up to 165 Hz [amazon link for specs](https://www.amazon.in/Acer-Nitro-23-8-1080-0-5-Response/dp/B088FLG41L?tag=georiot-in-default-21&ascsubtag=tomshardware-in-7041584176358116000-21&geniuslink=true)). The monitor has two HDMI 2.0 ports and 1 DP port. My laptop has no DP port and I think the HDMI port is 1.4 according to [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-well-would-the-NVIDIA-GeForce-MX150-work-with-external-monitors-not-for-gaming). So I connect through an HDMI cable. Nvidia control panel only shows 3d settings:

[image: link]

Now I will explain the problem I have started facing recently. When I first bought the monitor my fps was capped to 30 fps when I selected full-screen mode in Valorant. But selecting windowed full-screen (1920 x 1080 120 Hz) resolution gave around stable 90-120 fps. So I continued playing in that mode. But recently I don't know how (maybe after some driver update) Valorant displays wrong monitor resolution.

Please see this screenshot
[image: this]

. My monitor is not 4k but it displays 3840 x 2160 Monitor resolution. Even when I have selected 1920 x 1080 120 hz resolution the game is very laggy and I get 20-70 fps (it drops from 60-70 to 20 fps during gun fights and other interactions). Earlier the Monitor option displayed VG240YS (1920 x 1080 16:9) instead of ACR0750 (3840 x 2160 16:9). ACR0750 is the monitor id.

My problem is similar to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VALORANT/comments/o12vm2/valorant_stuck_to_30_fps_on_external_monitor/) and also [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ValorantTechSupport/comments/l3tru6/valorant_stuck_at_30hz/).

3840 x 2160 is also the max resolution I can select in my display settings.

[image]

I think the problem is something to do with active signal mode or wrong gpu native resolution. Please also go through [this answer](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/426287/nvidia-graphics-streams-wrong-active-display-signa/?topicPage=8&ncid=afm-chs-44270&ranMID=44270&ranEAID=kXQk6*ivFEQ&ranSiteID=kXQk6.ivFEQ-Kj3IUuugf9Zbnl6YBXwi3w). I have no compatibility mode option in my monitor menu.
There is no dsr or any scaling option in nvidia control panel.

I have tried most of the solution I referenced in my post but they either don't work or are not applicable to my setup. I really don't know what I did wrong because the game ran smoothly 1 month back with the correct monitor resolution diplayed.

Comment: I have this same monitor and I think it is reporting reporting 4K support itself, possibly due to the fact that the monitor itself can do 4k -> 1080p scaling which might result in slightly better picture quality and HDR. If you don't want the 4K support then you should just turn the game/display setting back down to 1920x1080.

Comment: How do I turn it down to 1920x1080. There is only one Monitor option (4k resolution) that you can see in the game settings screenshot. My nvidia control panel has no display settings

Comment: Your game is at 1920x1080, as stated in the Resolution field. The Monitor field is just making sure you know what screen you are on and what the system thinks it is capable of. Have you rebooted your computer recently? Not shutdown, reboot. Then try the game again.

Comment: @Mokubai my monitor is 1080p not 4k, Also I have tried everything including reinstalling windows but it did not solve my problem